# How to delete image using image_id with image_id pass as a parameter in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to delete image using image_id

with image_id pass as a parameter in django rest framework

Comment: Provide your model and view

Answer (score 0):

> models.py

```
class UploadImage(models.Model):

img_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.image
```

> views.py

```
class DeleteImageAPIView(APIView):

permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def post(self, request , format=None):
    img_id = request.POST.get('img_id')

    try:
        img = get_object_or_404(UploadImage, img_id=img_id)
        print(img_id)
        img.delete()
        return Response({
            'status' : True,
            'message' : 'Image Deleted Successfully',
        },status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
    except:
        return Response({
            'status' : 'False',
            'message' : 'Error! Image with this id does not exist!'
        }, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

> urls.py

```
    url(r'^delete_img',DeleteImageAPIView.as_view(), name='delete_event'),
```

> Post Method :

hit the img_id as a key and feel the img_id and send the data

> response :

status : 200 OK if img_id exist

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Image Deleted Successfully"
}
```

or status : 400 Bad Request if img_id not exist!

```
{
"status": "False",
"message": "Error! Image with this id does not exist!"
}
```

finally you are good to go;)